# How to install an OCaml variant like 4.08.0+fp+flambda via Esy?

Tags: ocaml, opam, esy

When installing OCaml packages via `esy` (instead of `opam`), which `package.json` entry is needed to install a specific OCaml variant, such as "4.08.0+fp+flambda" instead of "4.08.0"?

I tried several variants of the following, which does not work:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "ocaml": "4.08.0+fp+flambda",
    ...
  }
}
```

Error message:

```
No package matching:

  ocaml@=4.8.0+fp

  Versions available:

    ocaml@4.8.1000
    ocaml@4.8.0
    ocaml@4.7.1004
    ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All esy variant are stored here https://github.com/esy-ocaml/ocaml/tree/4.7.1000+esy+flambda in fact each ocaml version is on a branch. You see special commit to see how flambda option is added and do the same with your custom variant. You should fork it and point resolution of the form
`"ocaml": "github:user/esy-ocaml-fork#specificcommit"` or 
`"ocaml": "github:user/esy-ocaml-fork:package.json#specificcommit"`

Comment: What is the fork good for? Why can't I simply refer to the branch directly?

Comment: actually nobody asked for this branch: so you can fork create a branch (so you can 
 use it). And open PR if you want. If you want explain me what arg should be passed to the configure to enable `+fp`. And I will fork and do the necessary stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! FWIW, I also raised this question on GitHub where I got the following, quite informative, response: https://github.com/esy-ocaml/ocaml/issues/31

Comment: Et7f3XIV: Thanks for the offer, but adding supporting for my particular use case feels like a waste of time for me, that would better be spent in providing automatisms to keep in sync with all ocaml-variants automatically. See my GitHub link for more information.